# How to update selected document in the backend using formula language?

Tags: lotus-formula

In a view I have created a checkbox action button. The action button shows/hides the checkbox based on the formula I have set:

Form = "PrfForm" & AllotmentApprovalReq = "Yes"

Also I have checked "Evaluate actions for every document change" from the view properties. So based on the field "AllotmentApprovalReq" in the selected document the menu correctly shows/hides the checkbox on document selection.

Now what I want is that clicking this action button will do two things:

- Set/Reset the field "AllotmentApprovalReq" which itself is a checkbox, in the selected document, depending upon its previous state.
- Toggle the status of the checkbox menu, that is, show checkbox or hide it, again depending upon its previous state.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I've answered, but have you read *any* documentation for Lotus Notes formula language, or taken any on-line training? Setting fields is the first thing you should have learned.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a field is as easy as

```
FIELD AllotmentApprovalReq := "Yes";
```

Or

`FIELD AllotmentApprovalReq := "No";`

If you want to toggle the value, then you would use

```
FIELD AllotmentApprovalReq := @If(AllotmentApprovalReq = "Yes";"No";"Yes");
```

Since you have already set 'Evaluate actions for every document change', you should not have to do anything to refresh the action button. It should be automatic.

Comment: Well. I had tried it before posting this question. Tried some other variations as well like:  

@SetField("ServerPath";"ThisIsTheServerPath")

Nothing worked at all. I know that FIELD syntax works well in the agent but I have to do it under the click event of button in the view.

Comment: Is the preview pane open by any chance?  Even a single pixel can interfere because the action button will execute in the document's context instead of the view's context. When it executes in the document's context, the document has to be put into edit mode in order for any changes to be made, and you will have to do an explicit save. Somewhere around 20 years ago I knew a way to detect this situation, but I'd have to dig very deep in order to recall what it was.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the complete solution. I used lotus script instead of formula and it is working perfectly now :) Anyways thanks for your help.

Here's the solution:

- From the View property check "Evaluate action for every document change".
- Make the action button as a checkbox (type=Checkbox) and set like this formula to toggle check/uncheck:

  `Form = "AddCRM" & AllotmentApprovalReq = "Yes"`
- Now based on this field AllotmentApprovalReq which is a checkbox in the selected document, the action menu button will be shown as checkbox or no-checkbox, but of course label will be there.
- Now the following Click event for this action menu will update the checkbox status both in the selected document and the action menu:

```vba
    ' In the selected document, toggle AllotmentApprovalReq checkbox value
    ' depending upon its  previous value.   
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim uiview As NotesUIView       
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim CheckboxFlag As String

    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase  
    Set uiview = ws.CurrentView     

    Set doc = db.GetDocumentByID(uiview.CaretNoteID)
    CheckboxFlag = doc.GetItemValue("AllotmentApprovalReq")(0)

    If CheckboxFlag = "" Then
        CheckboxFlag = "Yes"    
    Else            
        CheckboxFlag = ""                   
    End If

    Call doc.ReplaceItemValue( "AllotmentApprovalReq", CheckboxFlag )

    Call doc.Save(True, False)

    Call ws.ViewRefresh
```